# Nothing is being inserted into sql table except id and date values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert post details into a SQL table, but only my `id` and `date` values are inserted and all the other columns remain blank.

Here is my form's HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xmudios14285</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/foundation.min.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <form action="chapter_exec.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Spear : </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="spear"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Chapter Name : </td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="cont_head"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Documented from : </td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="doc_from"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Image address : </td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="img_add"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Photo Courtesy : </td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="photo_add"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td > 
                    <textarea  name="content"></textarea> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the the PHP with the SQL query:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    $spear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['spear']);
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cont_head']);
    $docFrom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['doc_from']);
    $imageAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['img_add']);
    $photoCourt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['photo_add']);
    $doc_at = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
    if (!mysql_query("INSERT INTO chapters(spear, cont_head, doc_from,   `enter code here`img_add,    photo_add, doc_at, content) VALUES ('$spear', '$title', '$docFrom', '$imageAdd', '$photoCourt', '$doc_at', '$content')"))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    } else {
        header("location: dashboard2.php?remarks=postSubmitSuccesfull");
        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please **don't** use the deprecated `mysql_` extension. Switch over to something like `pdo` or `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: 'enter code here' is not in my code. it's because of some copy/paste mistake.

Comment: i know you are right, i'm converting all codes to mysqli but for current time,   i.m searching for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `POST` `method` attribute to your form like this:

```
<form action="chapter_exec.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: thanx a lot.... i just forgot to use method attribute in my form. A minor mistake..

Answer (score 2):

Form method is missing .

Default method for form is "**GET**" and you are using to receive data using **$_POST** method .Correct this issue using **method="post"**.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your form tag with:

```
<form action="chapter_exec.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

to verify that you post values are getting corretly, write oh php file:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, put the `method = POST` in your `<form>` tag, add a hidden field for `secure-checking` in the php.

```
<form action="chapter_exec.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- blah3 -->
<input type = "hidden" name = "check">
</form>
```

And then in your `php` use a `isset` like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['check']){
    $spear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['spear']);
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cont_head']);
    $docFrom = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['doc_from']);
    $imageAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['img_add']);
    $photoCourt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['photo_add']);
    $doc_at = mysql_real_escape_string(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));
    $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
        if (!mysql_query("INSERT INTO chapters(spear, cont_head, doc_from,   `enter code here`img_add,    photo_add, doc_at, content) VALUES ('$spear', '$title', '$docFrom', '$imageAdd', '$photoCourt', '$doc_at', '$content')"))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   } else {
   header("location: dashboard2.php?remarks=postSubmitSuccesfull");
   mysql_close($con);
}
?>
}
```